# How to trigger a task externally in a dag cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer

I want to have a data pipeline that essentially looks like this

[image]

where multiple tasks are triggered by corresponding pubsub messages, process data from pubsub messages' input, and the last task is triggered only when all these workflows are done. I manage to trigger the whole DAG using PubSub (following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#triggering-with-gcf-creating-a-function-python) with modifications for PubSub), but it triggers the whole DAG as opposed to a single task. Is there a way to only trigger 1 task in a DAG externally (from Cloud Function/PubSub?)

#### EDIT

This is a shortened version of how I thought the DAG code could be:

```
import google.cloud.bigquery as bigquery

import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from airflow.operators import dummy_operator


def task1_1(**kwargs):
    # I want this function to take the table name of source 1 from pubsub1, reads the table from BigQuery and processes it
    client_bq = bigquery.Client()
    table_name = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('message')
    data = client_bq.query(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}").result().to_dataframe()
    # ETL Code
    # ..... 


def task2_1(**kwargs):
    # I want this function to take the table name of source 2 from pubsub2, reads the table from BigQuery and processes it
    client_bq = bigquery.Client()
    table_name = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('message')
    data = client_bq.query(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}").result().to_dataframe()
    # ETL Code
    # ..... 

def task_combine():
    # This task is triggered when task1_1 and task2_1 are done
    # More ETL code


with DAG(
        'clean_am_workflow',
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=5),
        catchup=False) as dag:

    source_1 = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_source_1',
        python_callable=task1_1,
        provide_context=True
        )

    source_2 = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_source_2',
        python_callable=task2_1,
        provide_context=True
        )

    combine = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='combine_sources',
        python_callable=task_combine,
        provide_context=True
        )

    [source_1, source_2] >> combine
```

Comment: Hello, please fix the link in your question and please share your dag.

Comment: @PeterRing I fixed it and added the code but I dont know if it's of much help. It's how I want the DAG to be. Do you need to see the Cloud Function that triggers the DAG too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not to trigger the dag itself, but to trigger the different task separately based on bigquery. This can be achieved by an airflow sensor.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/index.html
SQL sensor:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/sql.html

In this case the dag will be triggered by a normal cron. The 2 sensor task will periodically query bigquery, if that query returns 'good to go' then it will start the tasks. Because the 2 sensor is independent the last task will only be executed when both sensor and task is done.

Comment: thank you for your answer! can airflow sensor senses a newly created table in a bigquery dataset?